# Hyperledger Node-Red query instruction

Tags: node-red, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am trying to query some data from a Hyperledger composer-rest-server using Node-Red. I am using the node-red-contrib-hyperledger-composer 1.0.1 add-on for Node-Red. I am able to create new assets and participants, but I am not able to query data.  However, I am able to query data using the http://localhost:3000/explorer.
How should my query command look like? How do I specify whether my command should be a "GET" or "POST" instruction?

Thank you so much in advance for your help!!!

Answer (score 3):

The latest version of he node red nodes are in the package node-red-contrib-composer npm module not node-red-contrib-hyperledger-composer.

It is not yet possible with the node red nodes to submit a query directly. You could create a GitHub issue for this though or even better add the functionality yourself!

It is possible though to submit a transaction that runs a query and use a query that way